# Microdisplacement "on" in the middle of a large project

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, displacement

What would be the effects of enabling microdisplacement in a large project that is already exists - and using it for new mesh items that are added/adjusted/replaced?[image]

Comment: Please describe in more detail how the existing scene is setup, and how you intend to use the microdisplacement. In general it should allow you to reduce usage of subdiv modifiers in favour of letting the renderer sort it out. This may lead to memory reductions when rendering and easier viewport navigation, but without knowing how subdivision is used in the scene it is hard to say.

Comment: the above scene is pushing 32mil verts - and makes it hard to work with.  Some of the mesh was made with using a displacement modifier - but then i applied it - so the mesh is "final" (guess will not help with those.

Comment: What I would like to do is add in/replace some of the structures and using (better efficient I believe) mesh with subdivision modifier and the microdisplacement - but my question is will the scene still work?  or do you need to start a microdisplacement mesh from the very start?   (in the above example the yellow/gold are oligodendrocytes - a brain cell - but in my scene they are way to dense with vertex count, I was going to remesh them and then use subdivision modifier and the microdisplacement. (I am sorta new to blender and sometimes I am not even positive what I am trying to ask - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played around too much myself with microdisplacement, but it sound like what you want to do should work. You will want to make sure you also have adaptive subdivision set to get the best performance. You may still want some of the displacement to come from the displace modifier though, this will require a bit of testing to see what works best.

With remeshing, you may instead want to look at the unsubivide setting on the decimate modifier if the scene was created with applied subdivision modifiers, you will end up with better topology for subdivision.

If viewport performance is the main consideration, you may also want to take a look at the simplify settings under scene properties. It give you the option to control the maximum viewport subdivision for all subdivision modifiers.

Comment: Thanks - all great ideas.   The viewport is sluggish at the 32mil verts for sure (but wireframe and bounding box help).   I did the remesh by hand with a shrinkwrap mod as the decimate modifier was giving me weird results.   Thanks much for the help.  I started working on the adjustments and all seems ok so far!